# React-Router DOM not rendering the content from other pages

Tags: reactjs

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';
import About from './About';
import Nav from './Nav';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function Web() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Nav />
                <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" Component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

const Home = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Home page</h1>
    </div>
);

export default Web;

//  Nav.js
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
                <Link to="/contact">
                    <a class="navbar-brand">Contact</a>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/about">
                    <a class="navbar-brand">about</a>
                </Link>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}

export default Nav;

//Contact.js
import React from 'react';

class Contact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>CONTACT PAGE</h1>;
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

When I don't use the react-router it works fine and renders the contact page. When it comes to react router This renders only the NavBar page .When I click the Contact link in the Navbar the url changes but it's an empty page.I might have done some mistake but could not find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name of props for `<Route />` component should be camel cased with starting lower case letter.

You have:

```js
<Route exact path='/' Component={Home} />
```

Try this:

```js
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 2):

All `children` of a `Switch` component should be either `Route` or `Redirect` components.

Also, you are never passing the `component` prop to the route components because you have the prop name(as "Component") uppercased.

```js
function Web()  {

  return (
    <Router>
       <Nav /> /* Nav should be outside of the switch */
       <Switch>
           <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />  /* lowercased prop name */
           <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `Nav` component out of `switch`. i.e

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';
import About from './About';
import Nav from './Nav';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function Web() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Nav />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" Component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

const Home = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Home page</h1>
    </div>
);

export default Web;

//  Nav.js
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
                <Link to="/contact">
                    <a class="navbar-brand">Contact</a>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/about">
                    <a class="navbar-brand">about</a>
                </Link>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}

export default Nav;

//Contact.js
import React from 'react';

class Contact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>CONTACT PAGE</h1>;
    }
}

export default Contact;
```